# Estoy empezando a ver los arrays y me piden

Tags: java, array, visual-studio, netbeans, intellij-idea

Estoy empezando a ver los arrrays y me piden un ejercicio en el que tenga que buscar el numero mayor y menor y aparte la suma de todos los valores. Yo he intentado hacerlo con este codigo pero no me llega a dar lo que necesito y no veo el problema.
Si me podeis explicar como podria hacerlo.. mi profesor no me explica bien las cosas. Gracias

```
    "int numero[] = new int[10];
    int mayor=0, menor = 99999;
    int sumaTotal = 0;
    Scanner teclado= new Scanner (System.in);"
    
    System.out.println("PROGRAMA QUE LOCALICE EL MENOR Y EL MAYOR NUMERO DENTRO DE UN ARRAYS  Y DESPUES LOS SUME ");
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    System.out.println("Introduzca la longitud del array: ");
    int arraySize = teclado.nextInt(); 
    int array[]= new int[arraySize];
    
   
   "" for (int i = 0; i < numero.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("ingrese num.: ");
        numero[i] = teclado.nextInt();
    if (numero[i] > mayor) {
        mayor = numero[i];
    } if (numero[i] < menor) {
        menor = numero[i];
        sumaTotal+=array[i]; "" 
        
        
    }
} 
   
    System.out.print("numero mayor: " + mayor);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("numero menor: " + menor);
    System.out.println("");

    for (int i = 0; i < numero.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("numeros: " + numero[i]);
    System.out.println("Suma:"+ sumaTotal); // Pintamos por pantalla el tamaño total
}
```

}
}

Comment: Hola, ¿Podrías poner tu código final?

El código que has subido no está bien.

Y sin entrar en ese tema, viendo lo que haces no tiene sentido. Me explico:
    - Solo estás sumando (sumaTotal+=array[i]) cuando el número introducido es menor que el valor almacenado en la variable menor. en otro caso no lo sumas.
    - El valor que estás asignado a sumaTotal lo obtienes de array que no tiene ningún valor, solamente está incializado.

Answer (score 0):

Aca tienes un ejemplo del cual puedes guiarte

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int[]arreglo={4,10,5,6,10,3,10,3,10,6,7,8,9,11,12}; 

int mayor=0;
for (int i=0;i<arreglo.length ;i++ ) {
    if(arreglo[i]>mayor){
            mayor=arreglo[i];
    }
     }

System.out.println("El mayor es: "+mayor);

int menor =arreglo[0];
for (int i=0;i<arreglo.length ;i++ ) {
    if(arreglo[i]<menor){
        menor=arreglo[i];
         } 
           }

System.out.println("El menor es:"+ menor);

int suma=0;

for(int i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++){
  suma=suma+arreglo[i];
}

System.out.println("La suma total es: "+ suma);
 
      }
```